# My kubernetes pods are Evicted repetitively

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-ec2, devops, kubernetes-pod

I have a k8s environment, where I am running 3 masters and 7 worker nodes. Daily my pods are in evicted states due to disk pressure.

I am getting the below error on my worker node.

```
Message:        The node was low on resource: ephemeral-storage.
```

```
Status:         Failed
Reason:         Evicted
Message:        Pod The node had condition: [DiskPressure].
```

But my worker node has enough resources to schedule pods.

Comment: The particular resource your worker nodes are running out of is disk space, not CPU or memory.  Are your processes leaking log files or otherwise using up large amounts of local disk?  Do you need to mount a volume instead of using the container filesystem?

Comment: Thanks, @DavidMaze,
Yes, my worker node running out of disk space. Also, I am using Volumes.
If I clear my storage does it fix my issue permanently? Previously I had a similar issue where my worker node disk space is fine but still, my pods are in the evicted state.
Also, worker node resources or container resources utilization causes my pod to get evicted?

Comment: A pod will get Evicted if it's actually using more resources than the node has physically available; which one depends on how much the pod is over its resource requests.  You need to manually delete the Evicted pods (though they don't take up resources at that point).

Comment: @DavidMaze could you possibly post your comments as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having analysed the comments it looks like pods go in the Evicted state when they're using more resources then available depending on a particular pod limit. A solution in that case might be manually deleting the evicting pods since they're not using resources at that given time. To read more about Node-pressure Eviction one can visit [the official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/node-pressure-eviction/).